# Direction to university level instruction

Tags: graduate-school, teaching

I am a senior in computer science and I have tutored courses in Math and  CSC/CIS for the past two years and I enjoy it and studying research (aka reading industry evaluations and research essays that interest me).

The problem lies with my own thoughts on jumping directly into a masters, I do not believe my GPA is good enough to get past the requirements(3.25+) nor do I know if I wish to direct myself into research.My thought is to earn a graduate degree while working my job.

1. How important is an interest in research to working at a college?
2. Are "experts in the field" generally hired for education?
3. What are the best ways to get myself into academia without doctorate interests?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Academia.SE!  I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding your question.  Can you please try to edit to clarify?

Comment: I edited my post, sorry for the clarification issue and I hope this clears it up

Comment: @Reed - I personally found the original question clearer.  Congratulations on the job offer.  You could ask about tuition benefits and flex time (to attend class) before you give them your answer.  For teaching at the college level, the higher the degree the better -- a Master's will bring better job security and pay than a Bachelors, and a PhD will be even better still.  But I agree with mhwombat that CS provides more fluidity between industry and academia than many careers do.  Last comment: You won't know how your GPA is viewed without applying!  You can apply without having decided yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How important is an interest in research to working at a college?

This depends on the college/university. Some are more teaching-focussed; some are more research-focussed.

> Are "experts in the field" generally hired for education?

For computer science lecturers, industry experience *is* valued. So if you have industry experience, you might be hired for some lecturing positions even without an MSc or PhD. This depends on the country, of course.

> What are the best ways to get myself into academia without doctorate interests?

At the moment, you don't have industry experience or an advanced degree, so I think it would be difficult to get hired as a lecturer, even at a community college. So here are a couple of paths you might consider:

1. Work for a few years in industry to get some experience, then apply for a lecturing position.
2. Enter a master's program directly after you have your bachelor's degree. You will likely be assigned some light teaching duties as part of your funding.
3. Large companies often accommodate their employees to continue their eduction. This typically includes paying your tuition, and allowing some schedule flexibility. So you might pursue a master's part-time, while working and gaining industry experience. A lot of master's programmes in computer science-y fields (e.g., data mining) are specifically designed for part-time students.